# Symfony2 remove web from the url on the external server

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I've been looking for the solution for a long time. There are a lot of such topics and I know it. But I still can't figure it out. How can I remove `web` from the symfony2 project url? I tried to do this with `htaccess` looking like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work. It gives me an error:

```
 No route found for "GET /web/"
```

I really can't change the root directory on this server as only thing I have is FTP permission. Anybody has any idea for this?

Edit: I also tried a trick to put all the files from `web` in root directory and the rest of the project higher. The problem is the highest directory I have access to is the root.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory ?

Answer (score 0):

You shall need to update your virtual host config file and set the DocumentRoot to point to the web folder.

For example you may currently have it set as

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/
```

but you need to update it to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/myproject/web
```

More information can be found within the Symfony2 cookbook [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)

Also this shall stop anyone trying to access the config/parameters.yml